# How to find and get string after a string known values in a text file c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, winforms

**I want to find and get a string after a string known values in a text file with c#**

**My text file:**

```
function PreloadFiles takes nothing returns nothing

call Preload(  "=== Save ===" )
call Preload( "Player: Michael" )
call Preload( "-load1 UvjkiJyjLlPN1o7FCAwQ0en80t769u5uBKAL1t0u0Cajk86WNmp83F" )
call Preload( "-load2 IMdOIPKGSDFXStx4Zd4LAvAaBmHW19rxsvSNF6kaObSFyBzGq8skYGuq0T1eW" )
call Preload( "-load3 Bd6MoyqnfDydBbwqGApWii3mabJpwNvjcwrKLI0r6UU2wadrMV1h7WQ8D6" )
call Preload( "-load4 D5kI18Flk5bJ4Oi7vQw33b5LHDXHGgJNYsiC6VNJDAHe1" )
call Preload(  "KEY PASS: 3568" )

endfunction
```

**i want to get string after string "-load1" ,"-load2" ,"-load3" ,"-load4" ,"KEY PASS: " and fill them on 5 Textbox**

**like that**

```
UvjkiJyjLlPN1o7FCAwQ0en80t769u5uBKAL1t0u0Cajk86WNmp83F
IMdOIPKGSDFXStx4Zd4LAvAaBmHW19rxsvSNF6kaObSFyBzGq8skYGuq0T1eW
Bd6MoyqnfDydBbwqGApWii3mabJpwNvjcwrKLI0r6UU2wadrMV1h7WQ8D6
D5kI18Flk5bJ4Oi7vQw33b5LHDXHGgJNYsiC6VNJDAHe1
3568
```

**Please help me**

**Thanks you!**

Comment: Are those all GUARANTEED to be on their own LINE (with nothing else before or after on the same line)?  How big is the file (approximately how many lines)?  How often will this occur?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
string Substring (int startIndex);
```

like:

```
string in1 = "-load1 UvjkiJyjLlPN1o7FCAwQ0en80t769u5uBKAL1t0u0Cajk86WNmp83F";
string out = in1.substring(7);
```

it returns:

```
"UvjkiJyjLlPN1o7FCAwQ0en80t769u5uBKAL1t0u0Cajk86WNmp83F"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do with `Regex` class (from `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace).

Patterns examples:

- for `-loadN ...` string: `" [A-Za-z0-9]*\" "`. It means Regex should look for substring which starts with whitespace `" "` contains some amount of chars `(A-z)` (of any case) or digits `(0-9)` and ends with double quote `\"` and whitespace `" "`. Such as yours  `UvjkiJyjLlP..."` .
- for `KEY PASS: ...` string: `@"KEY PASS: (\d{4})"`. This means Regex should find a substring which contains `"KEYPASS: "` text and some `string of 4 digits` and with whitespace `" "` between them.

But **aware**, it's **very unsafe**, because Regex patterns is **very sensitive**.
For example,

- `"-loaddd1 AbCdEfG..."` (extra chars)
- `"-load1   AbCdEfG..."` (multiple whitespaces)
- `"KEY PASS: 12345"` (pattern in example below looks strictly only for 4 digits, not 5 or more or less)
- `"-LOAD1 AbCdEfG..."` (uppercased)
  etc.

This ones will be ignored (last, btw, could be solved by passing `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` into `Regex.Match(line, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`). Others could be solved too, but you should know that this cases are possible.

For a provided in question example this code works fine:

```
string loadPattern = " [A-Za-z0-9]*\" ";
string keyPassPattern = @"KEY PASS: (\d{4})";

List<string> capturedValues = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("Preload.txt"))
{
    string s;

    if (Regex.IsMatch(line, loadPattern) && line.Contains("-load"))
    {
        // Getting captured substring and trimming from trailing whitespace and quote
        s = Regex.Match(line, loadPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value.Trim('\"', ' '); 
        capturedValues.Add(s);
    }
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(line, keyPassPattern))
    {
        // Just replacing "KEY PASS: " to empty string
        s = Regex.Match(line, keyPassPattern).Value.Replace("KEY PASS: ", ""); 
        capturedValues.Add(s);
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: thanksyou,it's work for me !

Answer (score 0):

```cs
string s1 = "-load1 UvjkiJyjLlPN1o7FCAwQ0en80t769u5uBKAL1t0u0Cajk86WNmp83F";

String filter = s1.ToString();

String[] filterRemove = filter.Split(' ');

String Value1= filterRemove[1];
```

In this way, you will get
`"UvjkiJyjLlPN1o7FCAwQ0en80t769u5uBKAL1t0u0Cajk86WNmp83F"` in value1

in the same way you can do for all the string and combine them.